# Office 365 Flow - getting bad request error when trying to retrieve the email ID from SharePoint Assigned To field

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, microsoft-flow, task-assignment

I am creating a new flow process. I am trying to send a simple email notification to a person whom the task is assigned. I am using OOTB task list and the flow is working file except that it is failing to retrieve the email address from the assigned to field.

I have also changed the field to person only and the value as email address but still i am getting the same issue.

Normally it works fine if it has send it to me - we can just leave it as blank but i want the notifications to go out to different people in the team.

Comment: MS Flow is a weird product thats recently created from the "great" MSFT. Can anyone  will think of creating a product with a  kind of defect like: when the developer created a Flow in O 365, and when he leaves the org., and when his user id stopped working , this Flow WILL STOP working. What do  you call this comedy? :-( So BEWARE of using this Flow product before implementing for your customer or try to use other successfull products like Nintex or K2 . Please take a caution and check with MS Engg Team - donno whether Jeff Teper is listening this not ! this flaw is fixed or not !

Comment: partially agreed but they have launched team flows where you or your team can control them now. also even user specific flows you can assign permissions to manage. But still lots of issues making the develops frustrated and might end up in loosing interest.

Comment: please follow https://twitter.com/MicrosoftFlow :-) also , please have a look at here : https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Flow-Community/ct-p/FlowCommunity?utm_source=t.co&utm_medium=referral

Comment: yes i do, there is a techcommunity as well. but still overall the product is not matured. instead MSFT should have called this as beta edition.

Comment: instead of building this kind of  *buggy* ( sorry for saying brutal :-(, am also in this beautiful MSFT SP world !!) product from scratch they could have gone ahead and acquired Nintex or K2 and integrate with O 365 !!!